# Getting error while updating the customer profile using customer ID

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am getting the following error while updating the all profile information of customer using its ID.

> Error:

```
Array
(
    [message] => Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [resources] => Magento_Customer::manage
        )

    [trace] => #0 
)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$response=array();
$adminUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "rajesh", "password" => "Abcd@987.");

$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$isPasswordChange=$_POST['isPasswordChange'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
if ($isPasswordChange==1) {
    $oldPassword=$_POST['oldPassword'];
    $newPassword=$_POST['newPassword'];
}
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mobusers where id='".$user_id."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $ent_id=$row['entity_id'];
    if ($dob=='' && $gender=='') {
        $customerData = [
            'customer' => [
                "id" => $ent_id,
                "email" => $email,
                "firstname" => $first_name,
                "lastname" => $last_name,
                "storeId" => 1,
                "websiteId" => 1,
                "customAttributes" => [
                    [
                    "attributeCode" => "mobile",
                    "value" => $mobile
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }else if ($dob !='' && $gender=='') {
        $customerData = [
            'customer' => [
                "id" => $ent_id,
                "email" => $email,
                "firstname" => $first_name,
                "lastname" => $last_name,
                "dob" => $dob,
                "storeId" => 1,
                "websiteId" => 1,
                "customAttributes" => [
                    [
                    "attributeCode" => "mobile",
                    "value" => $mobile
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }else if ($dob =='' && $gender !='') {
        $customerData = [
            'customer' => [
                "id" => $ent_id,
                "email" => $email,
                "firstname" => $first_name,
                "lastname" => $last_name,
                "gender" => $gender,
                "storeId" => 1,
                "websiteId" => 1,
                "customAttributes" => [
                    [
                    "attributeCode" => "mobile",
                    "value" => $mobile
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }else{
        $customerData = [
            'customer' => [
                "id" => $ent_id,
                "email" => $email,
                "firstname" => $first_name,
                "lastname" => $last_name,
                "gender" => $gender,
                "dob" => $dob,
                "storeId" => 1,
                "websiteId" => 1,
                "customAttributes" => [
                    [
                    "attributeCode" => "mobile",
                    "value" => $mobile
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
    $requestUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/'.$ent_id;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));   
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    print_r($result);exit;
    if (!isset($result['message']) && $result > 0) {
        $sql="UPDATE mobusers SET uemail='".$email."',mobile_no='".$mobile."'  WHERE id='".$user_id."' ";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if ($isPasswordChange==1) {
            $customerData=array("currentPassword"=>$oldPassword,"newPassword"=>$newPassword);
            $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
            $requestUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/password?customerId='.$ent_id;
            $ch = curl_init();
            $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));   
            $result1 = curl_exec($ch); 

            $result1 = json_decode($result1, 1);
            if (!isset($result1['message']) && $result1 > 0) {
                $sql="UPDATE mobusers SET password='".$password."'  WHERE id='".$user_id."' ";
                $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            }
        }
        if ($sql) {
            $response['status']="Success!";
            $response['msg']="Your profile has been updated successfully.";
        }
    }
}else{
    $response['status']="Error";
    $response['msg']="Failed!";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Here I am sending data from `postman` and trying to update all data as per `customer id` . Means if `isPasswordChange==1` then I am updating also the password but in my case I am getting those error. Please help me to resolve this issue and update all data as expected.

Comment: you need customer token

Comment: Here I can generate the admin token . you mean before updating the customer token needed right ?

Comment: yes, you must pass customer token insted of admin token while use this type URL  `customers/me`  in API.

Comment: But here I am trying to update by `customer id`.

Comment: @kunj : I also add the same customer token but same error coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me.

```
$customerData=array("customer_id"=> $ent_id,"currentPassword"=>$oldPassword,"newPassword"=>$newPassword);    
$requestUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/password';
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    $result1 = curl_exec($ch);
```

Sorry for the token it is working with admin token you just need to remove id from URL.